# Error parsing JSON

Tags: java, json, twitter, android-volley

I'm working with Volley and org.json to pull a JSON from a users timeline in twitter. I received a "Error with Request" from my onErrorResponse. It doesn't seem to be a URL problem because I see the desired JSON in the LogCat. Here's the error log:

```
11-30 22:54:52.273: W/TweetLoader(18610): Error with request
11-30 22:54:52.273: W/System.err(18610): com.android.volley.ParseError: org.json.JSONException: Value [{"contributors":null,"text":"18-propeller copter might be the future of personal air travel, inventors say.\nhttp:\/\/t.co\/TMUtbF80Kp via @CNNTech","geo":null,"retweeted":false,"in_reply_to_screen_name":null,"possibly_sensitive":false,"truncated":false,"lang":"en","entities":{"urls":[{"display_url":"cnn.it\/1bWid4q","expanded_url":"http:\/\/cnn.it\/1bWid4q","indices":[79,101],"url":"http:\/\/t.co\/TMUtbF80Kp"}],"hashtags":[],"user_mentions":[{"id":42703075,"indices":[106,114],"screen_name":"cnntech","id_str":"42703075","name":"cnntech"}],"symbols":[]},"in_reply_to_status_id_str":null,"id":406951229278146560,"in_reply_to_user_id_str":null,"source":"<a href=\"http:\/\/www.hootsuite.com\" rel=\"nofollow\">HootSuite<\/a>","favorited":false,"in_reply_to_status_id":null,"retweet_count":112,"in_reply_to_user_id":null,"created_at":"Sun Dec 01 01:01:48 +0000 2013","favorite_count":59,"id_str":"406951229278146560","place":null,"user":{"location":"","default_profile":false,"profile_background_tile":false,"statuses_count":36621,"lang":"en","profile_link_color":"004287","profile_banner_url":"https:\/\/pbs.twimg.com\/profile_banners\/759251\/1384971184","id":759251,"following":null,"favourites_count":4,"protected":false,"profile_text_color":"000000","contributors_enabled":false,"verified":true,"description":"Bringing you breaking news and the most talked about stories. Join the conversation and let’s connect!","profile_sidebar_border_color":"000000","name":"CNN","profile_background_color":"323232","created_at":"Fri Feb 09 00:35:02 +0000 2007","default_profile_image":false,"followers_count":11060197,"profile_image_url_https":"https:\/\/pbs.twimg.com\/profile_images\/378800000049679889\/9097753c470683f49aa12a6c15eba5c7_normal.jpeg","geo_enabled":false,"profile_background_image_url":"http:\/\/a0.twimg.com\/profile_background_images\/664730338\/60cc7d1f1b1a22a87ccccef026e15949.gif","profile_background_image_url_https":"https:\/\/si0.twimg.com\/profile_background_images\/664730338\/60cc7d1f1b1a22a87ccccef026e15949.gif","follow_request_sent":null,"entities":{"description":{"urls":[]},"url":{"urls":[{"display_url":"cnn.com","expanded_url":"http:\/\/www.cnn.com","indices":[0,22],"url":"http:\/\/t.co\/Db6JkaxJ9R"}]}},"url":"http:\/\/t.co\/Db6JkaxJ9R","utc_offset":-18000,"time_zone":"Eastern Time (US & Canada)","notifications":null,"profile_use_background_image":true,"friends_count":818,"profile_sidebar_fill_color":"EEEEEE","screen_name":"CNN","id_str":"759251","profile_image_url":"http:\/\/pbs.twimg.com\/profile_images\/378800000049679889\/9097753c470683f49aa12a6c15eba5c7_normal.jpeg","is_translator":false,"listed_count":88693},"coordinates":null},{"contributors":null,"text":"Will online classes make professors extinct? \nhttp:\/\/t.co\/g20MbYagb9 via @CNNOpinion","geo":null,"retweeted":false,"in_reply_to_screen_name":null,"possibly_sensitive":false,"truncated":false,"lang":"en","entities":{"urls":[{"display_url":"cnn.it\/1b4VUbw","expanded_url":"http:\/\/cnn.it\/1b4VUbw","indices":[46,68],"url":"http:\/\/t.co\/g20MbYagb9"}],"hashtags":[],"user_mentions":[{"id":259074538,"indices":[73,84],"screen_name":"CNNOpinion","id_str":"259074538","name":"CNN Opinion"}],"symbols":[]},"in_reply_to_status_id_str":null,"id":406921147427852288,"in_reply_to_user_id_str":null,"source":"<a href=\"http:\/\/www.hootsuite.com\" rel=\"nofollow\">HootSuite<\/a>","favorited":false,"in_reply_to_status_id":null,"retweet_count":186,"in_reply_to_user_id":null,"created_at":"Sat Nov 30 23:02:16 +0000 2013","favorite_count":98,"id_str":"406921147427852288","place":null,"user":{"location":"","default_profile":false,"profile_background_tile":false,"statuses_count":36621,"lang":"en","profile_link_color":"004287","profile_banner_url":"https:\/\/pbs.twimg.com\/profile_banners\/759251\/1384971184","id":759251,"following":null,"favourites_count":4,"protected":false,"profile_text_color":"000000","contributors_enabled":false,"verified":true,"description":"Bringing you breaking news and t
11-30 22:54:52.273: W/System.err(18610):    at com.android.volley.toolbox.JsonObjectRequest.parseNetworkResponse(JsonObjectRequest.java:73)
11-30 22:54:52.273: W/System.err(18610):    at com.android.volley.NetworkDispatcher.run(NetworkDispatcher.java:116)
11-30 22:54:52.293: W/System.err(18610): Caused by: org.json.JSONException: Value [{"contributors":null,"text":"18-propeller copter might be the future of personal air travel, inventors say.\nhttp:\/\/t.co\/TMUtbF80Kp via @CNNTech","geo":null,"retweeted":false,"in_reply_to_screen_name":null,"possibly_sensitive":false,"truncated":false,"lang":"en","entities":{"urls":[{"display_url":"cnn.it\/1bWid4q","expanded_url":"http:\/\/cnn.it\/1bWid4q","indices":[79,101],"url":"http:\/\/t.co\/TMUtbF80Kp"}],"hashtags":[],"user_mentions":[{"id":42703075,"indices":[106,114],"screen_name":"cnntech","id_str":"42703075","name":"cnntech"}],"symbols":[]},"in_reply_to_status_id_str":null,"id":406951229278146560,"in_reply_to_user_id_str":null,"source":"<a href=\"http:\/\/www.hootsuite.com\" rel=\"nofollow\">HootSuite<\/a>","favorited":false,"in_reply_to_status_id":null,"retweet_count":112,"in_reply_to_user_id":null,"created_at":"Sun Dec 01 01:01:48 +0000 2013","favorite_count":59,"id_str":"406951229278146560","place":null,"user":{"location":"","default_profile":false,"profile_background_tile":false,"statuses_count":36621,"lang":"en","profile_link_color":"004287","profile_banner_url":"https:\/\/pbs.twimg.com\/profile_banners\/759251\/1384971184","id":759251,"following":null,"favourites_count":4,"protected":false,"profile_text_color":"000000","contributors_enabled":false,"verified":true,"description":"Bringing you breaking news and the most talked about stories. Join the conversation and let’s connect!","profile_sidebar_border_color":"000000","name":"CNN","profile_background_color":"323232","created_at":"Fri Feb 09 00:35:02 +0000 2007","default_profile_image":false,"followers_count":11060197,"profile_image_url_https":"https:\/\/pbs.twimg.com\/profile_images\/378800000049679889\/9097753c470683f49aa12a6c15eba5c7_normal.jpeg","geo_enabled":false,"profile_background_image_url":"http:\/\/a0.twimg.com\/profile_background_images\/664730338\/60cc7d1f1b1a22a87ccccef026e15949.gif","profile_background_image_url_https":"https:\/\/si0.twimg.com\/profile_background_images\/664730338\/60cc7d1f1b1a22a87ccccef026e15949.gif","follow_request_sent":null,"entities":{"description":{"urls":[]},"url":{"urls":[{"display_url":"cnn.com","expanded_url":"http:\/\/www.cnn.com","indices":[0,22],"url":"http:\/\/t.co\/Db6JkaxJ9R"}]}},"url":"http:\/\/t.co\/Db6JkaxJ9R","utc_offset":-18000,"time_zone":"Eastern Time (US & Canada)","notifications":null,"profile_use_background_image":true,"friends_count":818,"profile_sidebar_fill_color":"EEEEEE","screen_name":"CNN","id_str":"759251","profile_image_url":"http:\/\/pbs.twimg.com\/profile_images\/378800000049679889\/9097753c470683f49aa12a6c15eba5c7_normal.jpeg","is_translator":false,"listed_count":88693},"coordinates":null},{"contributors":null,"text":"Will online classes make professors extinct? \nhttp:\/\/t.co\/g20MbYagb9 via @CNNOpinion","geo":null,"retweeted":false,"in_reply_to_screen_name":null,"possibly_sensitive":false,"truncated":false,"lang":"en","entities":{"urls":[{"display_url":"cnn.it\/1b4VUbw","expanded_url":"http:\/\/cnn.it\/1b4VUbw","indices":[46,68],"url":"http:\/\/t.co\/g20MbYagb9"}],"hashtags":[],"user_mentions":[{"id":259074538,"indices":[73,84],"screen_name":"CNNOpinion","id_str":"259074538","name":"CNN Opinion"}],"symbols":[]},"in_reply_to_status_id_str":null,"id":406921147427852288,"in_reply_to_user_id_str":null,"source":"<a href=\"http:\/\/www.hootsuite.com\" rel=\"nofollow\">HootSuite<\/a>","favorited":false,"in_reply_to_status_id":null,"retweet_count":186,"in_reply_to_user_id":null,"created_at":"Sat Nov 30 23:02:16 +0000 2013","favorite_count":98,"id_str":"406921147427852288","place":null,"user":{"location":"","default_profile":false,"profile_background_tile":false,"statuses_count":36621,"lang":"en","profile_link_color":"004287","profile_banner_url":"https:\/\/pbs.twimg.com\/profile_banners\/759251\/1384971184","id":759251,"following":null,"favourites_count":4,"protected":false,"profile_text_color":"000000","contributors_enabled":false,"verified":true,"description":"Bringing you breaking news and the most talked about
11-30 22:54:52.293: W/System.err(18610):    at org.json.JSON.typeMismatch(JSON.java:111)
11-30 22:54:52.293: W/System.err(18610):    at org.json.JSONObject.<init>(JSONObject.java:158)
11-30 22:54:52.293: W/System.err(18610):    at org.json.JSONObject.<init>(JSONObject.java:171)
11-30 22:54:52.293: W/System.err(18610):    at com.android.volley.toolbox.JsonObjectRequest.parseNetworkResponse(JsonObjectRequest.java:68)
11-30 22:54:52.293: W/System.err(18610):    ... 1 more
11-30 22:56:51.289: W/IInputConnectionWrapper(18610): setComposingText on inactive InputConnection
```

Here is the java files.

UPDATED TweetRequest.java

```
public class TweetsRequest extends JsonArrayRequest {

public TweetsRequest(String url, Listener<JSONArray> listener, ErrorListener errorListener,
        List<NameValuePair> params) {
    super(url + "?" + URLEncodedUtils.format(params, "UTF-8"), listener, errorListener);
}

@Override
public Map<String, String> getHeaders() throws AuthFailureError {
    Map<String, String> headers = new HashMap<String, String>();
    String auth = "Bearer " + TwitterValues.ACCESS_TOKEN;
    headers.put("Authorization", auth);
    return headers;
}
}
```

UPDATED TweetLoader.java

```
public class TweetLoader implements OnEndReachedListener {

private static final String LIST_URL = "https://api.twitter.com/1.1/statuses/user_timeline.json";
protected static final String TAG = TweetLoader.class.getSimpleName();
private ArrayAdapter<JSONObject> tweetAdapter;
private TweetJsonListener mDownListener = new TweetJsonListener();
private String query = "cnn";
private Activity activity;

public TweetLoader(ArrayAdapter<JSONObject> tweetAdapter, Activity activity) {
    this.tweetAdapter = tweetAdapter;
    this.activity = activity;
}

public void setQuery(String query) {
    tweetAdapter.clear();
    this.query = query;
    onEndReached();
}

@Override
public void onEndReached() {
    activity.setProgressBarIndeterminate(true);
    activity.setProgressBarIndeterminateVisibility(true);
    List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
    params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("screen_name", "cnn"));

    MainActivity.mRequestQueue.add(new TweetsRequest(LIST_URL, mDownListener, new ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            Log.w(TAG, "Error with request");
            error.printStackTrace();
        }
    }, params));
}

private class TweetJsonListener implements Listener<JSONArray> {

    public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
        JSONObject jsonObject = null;
        JSONArray tweets = response.optJSONArray("statuses");
        int count = tweets != null ? tweets.length() : 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
            jsonObject = tweets.optJSONObject(i);
            if (jsonObject != null) {
                tweetAdapter.add(jsonObject);
            }
        }
        activity.setProgressBarIndeterminateVisibility(false);
    }

    @Override
    public void onResponse(JSONArray arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }
}
}
```

TweetAdapter.java

```
public class TweetAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<JSONObject> {

private static final String TAG = TweetAdapter.class.getSimpleName();

public TweetAdapter(Context context) {
    super(context, 0);
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    ViewHolder holder;
    if (convertView == null) {
        convertView = LayoutInflater.from(getContext()).inflate(R.layout.twitter_item, null);
        holder = new ViewHolder();
        holder.imageView = (NetworkImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.profile_image);
        holder.nameView = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.name);
        holder.textView = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.text);
        convertView.setTag(holder);
    } else {
        holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
    }
    JSONObject currentItem = getItem(position);
    if (currentItem.length() == 0) {
        holder.nameView.setText(R.string.loading);
        holder.textView.setText("");
        holder.imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_launcher);
    } else {
        try {
            JSONObject user = currentItem.getJSONObject("user");
            holder.nameView.setText(user.optString("name", "<No name>"));
            holder.imageView.setImageUrl(user.getString("profile_image_url"), MainActivity.mImageLoader);
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        holder.textView.setText(currentItem.optString("text", "<No text>"));
    }
    return convertView;
}

private static class ViewHolder {
    private NetworkImageView imageView;
    private TextView nameView;
    private TextView textView;
}

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You didn't post your implementation of the `TweetRequest` class, but if I had to make an educated guess, I'm guessing that it inherits form the `JsonRequest` class which automatically casts the string response into a JSON **object**.

The thing is, the response you're receiving is a JSON **array**.

So if my guess was correct, your `TweetRequest` should inherit from `JsonArrayRequest` instead.

Did I read the situation correctly?

### EDIT:

OK, how about trying this:

Instead of converting a `JsonObject` to a `JsonArray` make your request an array request:

```
public class TweetsRequest extends JsonArrayRequest {
    // basically the same implementation you have now
}
```

You'll need to update your listeners because the response will now be a `JsonArray`.

### EDIT 2:

It seems you have left overs from the `JSONObject` request and listeners. This should be your `TweetJsonListener` - notice I've only use the correct method override and pasted your implementation into it. I did not validate your logic

```
private class TweetJsonListener implements Listener<JSONArray> {

    @Override
    public void onResponse(JSONArray response) {
        JSONObject jsonObject = null;
        JSONArray tweets = response.optJSONArray("statuses");
        int count = tweets != null ? tweets.length() : 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
            jsonObject = tweets.optJSONObject(i);
        if (jsonObject != null) {
            tweetAdapter.add(jsonObject);
        }

        activity.setProgressBarIndeterminateVisibility(false);

    }
}
```

Comment: I believe you have. I added TweetRequest, TweetLoader and TweetAdapter.java to the end of the post above. I've tried to fix the problem unsuccessfully with errors when converting the objects to arrays. If you could give me any advice where to start, I'd appreciate it @ItaiHanski

Comment: Thanks for the advice @ItaiHanski. I updated TweetRequest and TweetLoader.java to show array request and array listeners above. The problem now is I'm no longer getting a Parse error in LogCat or any errors in my code.The app is stuck at "Loading" with the progress bar spinning. Any ideas?

Comment: Not sure. There could be a bunch of reasons. The best thing to do is debug it and find the problem.

Comment: If you could look at one last thing because I think there's a problem with it but I'm not sure what it is, the last block in TweetLoader.java is having a problem with the onResponse, saying it's not used locally but it's used to describe "statuses" beneath it. Any idea what I'm doing wrong? Thanks again for all your help.

Comment: Thanks for catching that @ItaiHanski. The only error in your example was with response.optJSONArray where it wants an (int index) instead of "statuses". I'm confused by arrays. The listener worked to list Objects but I'm not sure I understand.

Comment: Try reading a bit about it here: http://www.json.org/javadoc/org/json/JSONArray.html